# Can you use a C# library in a AMP-server?

Tags: c#, php, linq-to-sql, joomla

Is it possible for me to build some database functionality in a C#-library (using LINQ 2 SQL) and then somehow import it into a php (joomla) project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) the .NET assembly as COM object (using `regasm.exe`) and then [consume](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) it from PHP.